# How to find text with a particular value BeautifulSoup python2.7

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following html: I'm trying to get the following numbers saved as variables Available Now,7,148.49,HatchBack,Good. The problem I'm running into is that I'm not able to pull them out independently since they don't have a class attached to it. I'm wondering how to solve this. The following is the html then my futile code to solve this.

```
</div>
<div class="car-profile-info">
<div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
<div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
<strong>Status:</strong> <span class="statusAvail">  Available Now </span><br/>
<strong>Min. Booking </strong>7 Days ($148.89)<br/>
<strong>Style: </strong>Hatchback<br/>
<strong>Transmission: </strong>Automatic<br/>
<strong>Condition: </strong>Good<br/>
</div>
```

Python 2.7 Code: - this gives me the entire html!

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.find("span",{"class":"statusAvail"}).getText()
for i in soup.select("strong"):
    if i.getText()=="Min. Booking ":
        print i.parent.getText().replace("Min. Booking ","")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all the strong elements under the `div` element with `class="car-profile-info"` and, for each element found, get the `.next_siblings` until you meet the `br` element:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

for strong in soup.select(".car-profile-info strong"):
    label = strong.get_text()
    value = ""
    for elm in strong.next_siblings:
        if getattr(elm, "name") == "br":
            break
        if isinstance(elm, Tag):
            value += elm.get_text(strip=True)
        else:
            value += elm.strip()

    print(label, value)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I wasn't aware of the next_siblings

Answer (score 1):

You can use  ".next_sibling" to navigate to the text you want like this:

```
for i in soup.select("strong"):
   if i.get_text(strip=True) == "Min. Booking":
       print(i.next_sibling) #this will print: 7 Days ($148.89)
```

See also http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-sideways

Comment: Thanks, I went with the other awnser above because of it being more comprehensive and completely solved the question. But I appreciate the link! I see what I missed in the doc.